# Spring Bean and @Autowired constructor with params

Tags: java, spring, javabeans, autowired

I would like to understand if is possible to use and how can I do to do a Bean with a @Autowired Constructor and params.

```
@Component
public class Routes
{
    private Foo req;

    @Autowired
    public Routes(Foo req)
    {
        this.req = req;
    }
    public String getUrl(String destin)
    {
        return req.getContextPath() + destin;
    }
}

@Component
public class HomeController
{
    @Autowired
    private Routes routes;

    public HomeController(Foo req)
    {
        String foo = routes.getUrl("something");
    }
}
```

REAL CODE ------EDITING---------------
The exception is happening on the line:
String foo = rt.getUrl("caca");

```
public class AppRun extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3308874705513248491L;

    private ApplicationContext context;

    @Override
    public void service(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        context = WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(getServletContext());

        FooTest ft = new FooTest();

        HomeControllerTest hc = (HomeControllerTest) context.getBean("homeControllerTest", new Object[]{ft});
    }
}

@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class FooTest {

    public String mensagem()
    {
        System.out.println("funcionou");
        return "ok";
    }

}

@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class RoutesTest {

    private FooTest req;

    @Autowired
    public RoutesTest(FooTest req)
    {
        this.req = req;
    }

    public String getUrl(String destin)
    {
        return req.mensagem().concat(destin);
    }

}

@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class HomeControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private RoutesTest rt;

    public HomeControllerTest(FooTest req)
    {
        String foo = rt.getUrl("caca");

        System.out.println(foo);
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried it? yes, it will work, but all parameters to the constructor must be available as @Components (or other similar annotation).

Comment: I try this, but I get this exception: 2012-11-08 14:49:15.908:WARN::Nested in org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'homeControllerTest' defined in file [D:\Eclipse\workspace\summer-mvc\target\classes\br\gov\pr\maringa\test\HomeControllerTest.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [br.gov.pr.maringa.test.HomeControllerTest]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException:
java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Please post the constructor for HomeControllerTest. Is this class strictly for testing? Does it belong as part of the production code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you are accessing a property in the constructor that is not valued yet: Spring must create the object before it can set the @Autowired property rt. Either add the argument `RoutesTest rt` to the constructor, or move your constructor logic to an `afterPropertiesSet` method.

Here is how to change your class that is failing, using the constructor:

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class HomeControllerTest {

    private RoutesTest rt;

    @Autowired
    public HomeControllerTest(FooTest req, RoutesTest rt)
    {
        this.rt = rt;
        String foo = rt.getUrl("caca");

        System.out.println(foo);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thx by your attention. Add RoutesTest rt to HomeControllerTest() ?? Could you to explain?

Comment: I edited the answer to show you what I meant by changing the constructor.

Comment: Hmmm fine. I get success!! Thx.